# How to pass the container version?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, portainer

I'm trying to pass the version of my container to a script running inside it, but I cannot find the proper way.

Currently, I write this in my dockerfile:

```
ARG VERSION_ARG="0.0"
ENV VERSION=$VERSION_ARG
```

I set the `VERSION-ARG` variable during the build:

```
docker build . --build-arg "VERSION_ARG=1.0"
```

And in the script, I execute the following:

```
echo $VERSION
```

And it prints out the correct number.

But when I use a container manager (like Portainer) to update, it still displays the old number afterwards, because it keeps all ENV variables (and other settings) the same when pulling an update of an image, to preserve your modifications.

Another problem is that users can very easily modify the version number reported to the container.

I thought about writing the version to a file during the build, and reading it from the script, as it would solve the above problems.

But are there any other ways to accomplish this? That don't involve `ENV` variabeles or including a file?

Comment: You should probably tag your question with the `portainer` tag, since this seems more like a portainer problem than a Docker problem. It's definitely not normal Docker behaviour.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks, I did that now. But I also saw this same behaviour on other container managers, like Docker for Synology DSM. And it makes sense, you dont want to loose all your existing ENV variabeles when updating.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the new image that you built? A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: @BMitch Yes, I'm sure. And I expected the behaviour that user-defined ENV variables override the default values from the images, so well-known that I didn't have to show how to reproduce that.

Comment: Why/how are you overriding the image variables? Seems like that's the issue here, but I'm not a Portainer user to be able to reproduce that.

Comment: @BMitch I'm not overriding them manually myself, but Portainer keeps your ENV variabeles (and all other settings) the same when updating the image. But this has nothing to do with Portainer, every other container manager that I know works this way (for good reasons). My question was: is there a way to pass the version without ENV variabeles? Not: should I use a container manager? A simple solution would be to pass the version via a file, that is written with a RUN command during build. But I just wanted to know if there are other ways that do not use ENV or files.

Comment: I'd consider portainer overriding the image variables without user direction as a defect in portainer. This doesn't happen in docker-compose, kubernetes, or any other container manager I've used.

Comment: @BMitch What happens is that when you edit the container, they show you the full list of ENV variabeles from the Dockerfile with their default values, so it is easy to edit them. When you later update the image, it doesn't change the list to preserve your modifications. What it should do ideally, is to only keep the values you modified manually, and forget the values you didn't modify from their defaults. But currently Portainer does not do that, and Docker for Synology doesn't do that too. So I suspect it's a common problem amongst container managers with a GUI.